# -- --schema doesn't work with Sqoop create-hive-table

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop

HDP-2.5.0.0 using Ambari 2.4.0.1

I'm able to create a table in HCatalog from a SQL Server source db, for example :

```
sqoop import --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '\0D' --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --hcatalog-database MS_Management_Coaching --hcatalog-table TripAggregate --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza 'stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB")' --validate --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<DB server>;database=Management' --username uname--password pwd--table TripAggregate -- --schema Coaching
```

but when I try to use a the [--create-hive-table](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_create_hive_table_literal), the -- --schema option doesn't work, no matter where I position it :

```
-bash-4.2$ sqoop create-hive-table --hive-database test --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<DB Server>;database=Management' --username uname--password pwd--table TripAggregate -- --schema Coaching
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/12 21:28:13 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.0.0-1245
16/10/12 21:28:13 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/12 21:28:13 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for create-hive-table:
16/10/12 21:28:13 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --
16/10/12 21:28:13 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --schema
16/10/12 21:28:13 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: DriverCoaching
Try --help for usage instructions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the argument `--` is given on the command-line, then subsequent arguments are sent directly to the underlying tool.

After looking into sqoop code, I found that in `--create-hive-table` flow does not go to the underlying tool. That's why you are not able to use `-- --schema` in your command.

Useful part of [source code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/0f13c474bf91f6609b9bdd7a1aa25b250f07e398/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/tool/ImportTool.java#L1150)  for `ImportTool` :

```
 public void validateOptions(SqoopOptions options)
      throws InvalidOptionsException {

    // If extraArguments is full, check for '--' followed by args for
    // mysqldump or other commands we rely on.
    options.setExtraArgs(getSubcommandArgs(extraArguments));
    int dashPos = getDashPosition(extraArguments);

    if (hasUnrecognizedArgs(extraArguments, 0, dashPos)) {
      throw new InvalidOptionsException(HELP_STR);
    }

    validateImportOptions(options);
    validateIncrementalOptions(options);
    validateCommonOptions(options);
    validateCodeGenOptions(options);
    validateOutputFormatOptions(options);
    validateHBaseOptions(options);
    validateHiveOptions(options);
    validateHCatalogOptions(options);
    validateAccumuloOptions(options);
  }
```

Useful part of [source code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/0f13c474bf91f6609b9bdd7a1aa25b250f07e398/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/tool/CreateHiveTableTool.java#L119)  for `CreateHiveTable` :

```
 public void validateOptions(SqoopOptions options)
      throws InvalidOptionsException {

    if (hasUnrecognizedArgs(extraArguments)) {
      throw new InvalidOptionsException(HELP_STR);
    }

    validateCommonOptions(options);
    validateOutputFormatOptions(options);
    validateHiveOptions(options);

    if (options.getTableName() == null) {
      throw new InvalidOptionsException(
          "--table is required for table definition importing." + HELP_STR);
    }
  }
```

you see no checking for `--` args is done in the later.

---

**Edit:**

`--hive-import` by default creates hive table and you can use  `-- --schema` with import command. If you want sqoop to create hive table for you and import data in that table. It should work for you.

Comment: So does it mean that --create-hive-table cannot read from the source schema ? Any workarounds that can be implemented ?

Comment: I am assuming without `--schema Coaching`  you are not able to read this table. So you can put your table in default schema (`dbo` I guess) and proceed. Or you can change source code of sqoop and build locally and proceed.

Comment: I wish to have just the table and NOT the data ;)

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist then changing table to public schema or changing source code are the available options..:D

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist you can use free form query and select no data.